# Reencode videos from 30fps to 60fps using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

If I have an mp4 with 30 fps, how do I re-encode it to 60 fps using ffmpg **without** making the movie speeding up faster (still looking normal)?

My ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
```

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to convert from 30 to 60 fps?

Comment: Maybe ask on superuser :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`-r` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 60 output.mp4
```

Or [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=60 output.mp4
```

`ffmpeg` will duplicate frames to convert from 30 to 60 fps, but it will still look normal.